# Why this order of words: יַגְדִּיל תּוֹרָה וְיַאְדִּיר

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk

We end the Rabbi Chananyah ben Akashya quote with a quote from [Yeshayahu 42:21](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1042.htm#21), the last 3 words of which say יַגְדִּיל תּוֹרָה וְיַאְדִּיר, meaning "Torah great and glorious" (which quote also appears elsewhere in the daily davening).

Why is the noun in the middle of two adjectives?  Why not have both adjectives before the noun?

Answer (score 1):

יַגְדִּיל is not an adjective, but a *hifil* verb form of the גדל root, and the same for יַאְדִּיר. In my Artscroll machzor at hand it is translated as *that the Torah be made great and glorious.* Therefore, *yagdil* is the [be made great](https://www.pealim.com/dict/300-lehagdil/) and *yaadir* is the [be made glorious](https://www.morfix.co.il/en/%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A8). So an awkward, but more literal translation would be:

> *Hashem* desired, for the sake of its righteousness that the Torah be made great and be made glorious.

Here the word order is not an issue, as you're just adding another verb to the list.

Comment: OK. Nevertheless, why the two verbs separated by the noun?

Comment: @YehudaW probably "poetic license". This technique is quite common in prayers.

Comment: @YehudaW Post another question... ;-)

Comment: Commentless downvote?